# Difference with the previous value. kslqDB

Tags: ksqldb

I was trying to make an example with ksqlDB

Based on two properties, in this case "sensor_id" and "user_id".

I calculated the variation of the "value" field, when both attributes match.

// TOPIC KAFKA

```
{"timestamp": 1000000000, "user_id": "AAAAA", "sensor_id": "sensor_1111", "value": 10000}
{"timestamp": 1555550000, "user_id": "AAAAA", "sensor_id": "sensor_1111", "value": 22000}

{"timestamp": 1666660000, "user_id": "AAAAA", "sensor_id": "sensor_2222", "value": 22000}
{"timestamp": 1777770000, "user_id": "AAAAA", "sensor_id": "sensor_2222", "value": 25000}

{"timestamp": 1666660000, "user_id": "BBBBB", "sensor_id": "sensor_2222", "value": 30000}
{"timestamp": 1777770000, "user_id": "BBBBB", "sensor_id": "sensor_2222", "value": 40000}
```

When that two values coincide, I calculated the difference with the previous one.

And the elapsed time.

// RESULT

```
{"timestamp": 1555550000, "last_timestamp": 1000000000, "user_id": "AAAAA", "sensor_id": "sensor_1111", "value": 12000}
{"timestamp": 1777770000, "last_timestamp": 1666660000, "user_id": "AAAAA", "sensor_id": "sensor_2222", "value": 3000}
{"timestamp": 1777770000, "last_timestamp": 1666660000, "user_id": "BBBBB", "sensor_id": "sensor_2222", "value": 10000}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should be possible using a custom user defined aggregate function or UDAF.

If you were to write a `Compare_to_previous` UDAF which stores the first value it receives and compares it to the second value, then you could achieve what you want with:

```sql
CREATE TABLE DIFF AS SELECT 
   user_id, 
   sensor_id,
   Compare_to_previous(ROWTIME) as last_timestamp,
   Compare_to_previous(value) as value
   GROUP BY user_id, sensor_id
   HAVING Compare_to_previous(ROWTIME) IS NOT NULL;
```

Where compare_to_previous might be something like (not tested):

```java
@UdafDescription(
    name = "COMPARE_TO_PREVIOUS",
    description = CompareToPrevious.DESCRIPTION
)
public final class CompareToPrevious {

  static final String DESCRIPTION = "Blah blah";

  // UDAF version for BIGINT:
  private static Udaf<Long, List<Long>, Long> compareToPrevious() {
    return new Udaf<Long, List<Long>, Long>() {

      @Override
      public List<Long> initialize() {
        // Initial value is empty() meaning no previous.
        return ImmutableList.of();
      }

      @Override
      public List<Long> aggregate(final Long current, final List<Long> previous) {
        if (current == null) {
          // Ignore null values? You're choice!
          return previous;
        }

        switch (previous.size()) {
          case 0:
            // 1st value seen for this key:
            return ImmutableList.of(current);
          case 1:
            // 2nd value seen for this key:
            return ImmutableList.of(previous.get(0), current);
          default:
            // Already seen two values - what to do?
            // Do you want to compare pairs
            // i.e. compare 2nd with 1st, then 4th with 3rd, etc.
            // return ImmutableList.of()
            // or
            // Or each subsequent row with previous,
            // i.e. you'd compare 2nd with 1st, then 3rd with 2nd etc.
            return ImmutableList.of(previous.get(0), current);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public List<Long> merge(final List<Long> aggOne, final List<Long> aggTwo) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "Compare_to_previous won't work with session windowed data");
      }

      // Call to convert the intermediate List<Long> into an output value.
      @Override
      public Long map(final List<Long> agg) {
        if (agg.size() != 2) {
          // If we don't have two values to compare we output NULL.
          // Use HAVING Compare_To_Previous(COL) IS NOT NULL in the query to exclude these null rows.
          return null;
        }

        // We have two values - calculate the diff:
        return ((long) agg.get(1)) - agg.get(0);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Such an aggregator won't be able to handle out-of-order data, but it will be suitable for many use cases.

Comment: Rather than using an `ARRAY` as the intermediate value, you could also use a `STRUCT<val1 BIGINT, val2 BIGINT>.

Your choice.